# Propagating user information to all layers in Dropwizard

Tags: authentication, dropwizard

I am using basic authentication mechanism in my Dropwizard application,  where I am capturing logged in user details, something like this:

```
@POST
@Timed
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces("application/pdf")
@Path("/")
@RolesAllowed("user,admin")
public Response function(@Auth User user) throws Exception {
    //some logic around here
}
```

Now for auditing purposes, I want this user information to be passed at each layer of my application, I mean in services, DAOs, ExceptionMappers etc and I don't want to pass it as function parameter everywhere as it looks clumsy and also has maintainability overhead. so my question is, is there any way by which we can set some global configuration per REST call or user session and can fetch it anywhere I want?
I have been a Ruby user and in that we were able to do something like this:

```
Thread.current[:user] = user
```

which which accessible throughout per user session.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by using [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) of Java wherein you can set the User object and it will be available to that particular executor thread.

Add the following to your resource class.

```
private static ThreadLocal<User> localUser = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

public static ShortenerServiceUser getUser() {
    return localUser.get();
}
```

Whennever your function() method is invoked, you just need to set the User object into the ThreadLocal variable.

```
localUser.set(user);
```

Now, whenever you need to access the User object from the current thread context, all you need to do is as follows

```
User localUser = YourResource.getUser();
```

You can clear the User object from the context by using the ThreadLocal.remove() method.